# Makefile use as an adapter to another build system

Tags: makefile

I need to create a Makefile used as an adapter to another build system that accept any target goals and just pass the goal name received as argument to shell command invoked. Here is what I have:

```
OTHER_BUILD_SYSTEM = other_build_system
$@:
    $(shell $(OTHER_BUILD_SYSTEM $@))
```

But make complains:

```
No rule to make target `xyz`. Stop.
```

Any clue on how I could do that?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might want a [Match-Anything Pattern Rule](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Match_002dAnything-Rules):

> When a pattern rule’s target is just `‘%’`, it matches any file name whatever. We call these rules *match-anything* rules. They are very useful, but it can take a lot of time for make to think about them, because it must consider every such rule for each file name listed either as a target or as a prerequisite.

You also don't want `$(shell)` in the recipe. Just put the shell command you want to run there directly.

```
OTHER_BUILD_SYSTEM = other_build_system
%:
    $(OTHER_BUILD_SYSTEM $@)
```

The [`shell` function](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Shell-Function) is a make level function used in non-recipe contexts to run shell commands.

That all said this seems like an odd thing to want to do. Could you not just call your other application directly? Or write a shell script/function called `make` that simply executes your other build tool instead? Also if this makefile is passed multiple targets it will invoke your other build tool N times instead of just once (in case that matters).